# Propety findOneTImeTokenCredentialsByEmail does not exist on type 'typeof CredentialsDao

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a method in my credentials service file that needs to access the method from another class called `CredentialsDao` like so:

```
disableOneTimeCredentials() {
  const emailAndOneTimeToken = CredentialsDao.findOneTimeTokenCredentialsByEmail()
}
```

This is whats generating that error:

The credentials dao file looks like so:

```
export class CredentialsDao {
  constructor() {
     this.findOneTimeTokenCredentialsByEmail = this.findOneTimeTokenCredentialsByEmail.bind(this)
  }

  async findOneTimeTokenCredentialsByEmail(email: string): Promise<ICredential> {
    return this.Model.findOne({
      email: email,
      credentialType: CredentialType.oneTimeToken,
      $or: [
        {
          disabledOn: null
        },
        // {
        //   disabledOn: {
        //     $exists: false  // hangs or return nothing... why?
        //   }
        // },
        {
          disabledOn: {
            $exists: true,
            $ne: null,
            $gt: new Date()
          }
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

And yes I did import the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the [static](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#static-members) members.

```
CredentialsDao.findOneTimeTokenCredentialsByEmail();
```

but the method is not marked as `static`

```
async findOneTimeTokenCredentialsByEmail(email: string): Promise<ICredential>

// static modifier
static async findOneTimeTokenCredentialsByEmail(email: string): Promise<ICredential>
```

Don't think you will be able to use `this` and reference non-static properties within the `static` method.

Perhaps an oversight, but will work if you create a new instance:

```
const service = new CredentialsDao();
service.findOneTimeTokenCredentialsByEmail('vader@ds.com');
```